# Generate R.Java and Layout - Intellij vs Eclipse

Tags: java, android

please look at this main.xml -

```
<TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:id="@+id/TableLayout03">
```

In eclipse its coming out fine, no errors and project is working
In Intellij its stopping my project from generating a R.java class file and if I undo the main.xml to the default,  R.java is present and its marking red a host of resource reference.e.g R.layout.main, R.id.myWebSite

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: add full xml file source

Answer (score 1):

```
<TableLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
```

İ think you should remove id part.